# The set of rational numbers doesn't satisfy the least-upper-bound property

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

This exercise is from Tom Apostol's *Calculus Vol.1*:

**I 3.12 Exercises (page 29)**

> 12) The Archimedian property of the real-number system was deduced as a consequence of the least-upper-bound axiom. Prove that the set of rational numbers satisfies the Archimedian property but not the *least-upper-bound property*. This shows that the Archimedian property does not imply the least-upper-bound axiom.

---

I don't get what I have to do, and what it means -- to **satisfy** the least-upper-bound-property. I know it is an axiom, I didn't know it is a **property**. My closest guess is that if I have two rational numbers $x < y$, I can find an integer $n$ such that $nx > y$. And I don't need to refer to that axiom, because I can find this $n$ by playing with the integers inside the rational numbers.

---

> Previously from the book:
>
> The Archimedian property (page 26): *If $x > 0$ and if $y$ is an arbitrary real number there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $nx > y$.*
>
> The least-upper-bound axiom (page 25): *Every nonempty set $S$ of real numbers which is bounded above has a supremum; that is, there is a real number $B$ such that $B = sup S$*.

---

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to construct the field of real numbers is axiomatically. In this approach, you have a collection of axioms you want to be true, one of them is that the real numbers satisfy the least upper bound property.

To show that $\mathbb{Q}$ satisfies the Archimedian axiom, you need to show that if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, $x > 0$, then for any $y \in \mathbb{Q}$, there is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $nx > y$.

To show that $\mathbb{Q}$ does not satisfy the least upper bound property, you need to find a subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ which is bounded above, but has no least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Your last paragraph is new to me. Because so far in the book I have not read what it means for a set to satisfy some property.

Comment: It seems that's because you've only seen the least upper bound property expressed for $\mathbb{R}$, but given any partially ordered set, you can ask whether or not it has the least upper bound property. In particular, you can ask the question of $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Graduate This is actually a reasonably fair point, since it isn't a clear definition.  Essentially you are expected to generalize the Archimedean and l.u.b. properties to other sets $F$ by replacing all instances of "real number" to "element of $F$" and all instances of $\mathbb R$ with $F$.

Comment: For me it's right to express the supremum for any set by any real number. For example a subset of *Q* can be bounded by an irrational number. There is nothing wrong with it since I can compare them. That's my understanding.

Comment: @Graduate Yes, but notice that in the substituted version it would require $B$ to be *rational* (an element of $\mathbb Q$) rather than real.

Comment: If you are thinking of $\mathbb{Q}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, this may seem like a reasonable thing to do, but we are asking about $\mathbb{Q}$ as an independent object. The point of the l.u.b. property is that least upper bounds exist *within* the set you're considering.

Comment: @ErickWong: A novice mathematician inside of me argues: "any rational number is a real number, so it's legitimate to bound it by a real number."

Comment: @Graduate I don't see how this addresses my second point.  The question is not about "legitimacy" but whether the property is true or not.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: *Apostol* didn't provide me with this understanding. So as he said, his book treats calculus in an informal style.

Comment: @Graduate: That's all well and good, but that is one reason misunderstandings can occur. Regardless of what the book does or doesn't do, there is a precise definition of what it means for a partially ordered set to satisfy the l.u.b. property. According to this definition, $\mathbb{Q}$ does not have this property.

Answer (score 9):

Here I prove the claim made in a previous answer, that the set
$$
\mathcal{S} = \left\{x\in\mathbb{Q} : x^2<2 \right\}
$$
does not have a least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Since $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{S}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Furthermore, $\mathcal{S}$ is non-empty (e.g. $1^2 < 2$) and is bounded above by definition, so by the completeness axiom it has a least upper bound in $\mathbb{R}$ - say $\sup\mathcal{S}=s$. We now show that $s = \sqrt{2}$.

There are only 3 possibilities: $s>\sqrt{2}$, $s<\sqrt{2}$, or $s=\sqrt{2}$.

The first possibility can be eliminated from the definition of $\mathcal{S}$. Clearly $\sqrt{2}$ is an upper bound of $\mathcal{S}$, since $x^2 < 2$ implies $x < \sqrt{2}$. Therefore any number larger than $\sqrt{2}$ cannot be the *least* upper bound.

To eliminate the second possibility, assume for contradiction that $s<\sqrt{2}$. Since the rationals are dense in $\mathbb{R}$, there is a rational $q$ such that $s<q<\sqrt{2}$. But this implies $q^2 < 2$ and so $q\in\mathcal{S}$, which means that $s<q$ cannot be an upper bound of $\mathcal{S}$.

We are left with $s=\sqrt{2}$. Since $\sqrt{2}\notin\mathbb{Q}$, $\mathcal{S}$ does not have a least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$ and so we have found a counterexample which shows that $\mathbb{Q}$ is not complete.

Answer (score 6):

For example, the set $\{ x\in\mathbb{Q} : x^2 <2 \} $ does not have a least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q} .$

Comment: My understanding is that this set has the least upper bound, but it is an irrational number (a square root of $2$). An irrational number is also a real number.

Comment: But You have to prove that the set of rational numbers satisfies the Archimedian property but not the least-upper-bound property.